# Django N+1 problem with serpy.MethodField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, select-n-plus-1

I use [nplusone](https://github.com/jmcarp/nplusone) to detect N+1 queries.

I have a [serpy](https://serpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) serializer that serializes `Order` instances. An `Order` has a `cart` consisting of `OrderComponent` instances, as shown below. Code simplified:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    objects = OrderManager()
    listings = models.ManyToManyField(to=Listing, through="OrderComponent", related_name="orders")


class OrderComponent(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(to=Listing, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="order_components")
    order = models.ForeignKey(to=Order, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="cart")
    nb_units = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

A list of serialized `Order` instances is gotten through `OrderListView`:

```
class OrderListView(SimplePaginatedListView):  # Custom base class
    model = Order
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    deserializer_class = OrderDeserializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().select_related(
            "fulfillment",  # Used for order.is_fulfilled()
            "cancellation",  # Used for order.is_cancelled()
        ).prefetch_related(
            "cart",  # I don't believe the first two are necessary, but added for testing purposes
            "cart__listing",
            "cart__listing__product",
            "cart__listing__service",
        )

    @http_get(required_permissions=ShopRolePermission.MANAGE_ORDERS)
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get(*args, **kwargs)

    @http_post(required_permissions=ShopRolePermission.MANAGE_ORDERS)
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().post(*args, **kwargs)
```

`OrderSerializer` is defined below. `nplusone` does not say where an N+1 query was detected, so I have commented out every possible culprit and found the true culprits. I have indicated in comments where they are.

```
class OrderSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    class SimpleOrderComponentSerializer(BaseSerializer):
        id = serpy.IntField()
        listing_id = serpy.IntField()
        product_name = serpy.MethodField(required=False)  # No N+1
        service_name = serpy.MethodField(required=False)  # No N+1
        nb_units = serpy.IntField()

        def __init__(self, instance=None, many=False, data=None, context=None, **kwargs):
            # Should this be necessary, since I prefetched in get_queryset?
            instance = instance.select_related("listing", "listing__product", "listing__service")
            super().__init__(instance, many, data, context, **kwargs)

        @staticmethod
        def get_product_name(_serializer, obj: OrderComponent):
            # No N+1
            return obj.listing.product.product_name if obj.listing.product else None

        @staticmethod
        def get_service_name(_serializer, obj: OrderComponent):
            # No N+1
            return obj.listing.service.service_name if obj.listing.service else None

    id = serpy.IntField()
    cancelled = serpy.BoolField(attr="is_cancelled")  # Checks if Cancellation instance exists, no N+1
    fulfilled = serpy.BoolField(attr="is_fulfilled")  # Checks if Fulfillment instance exists, no N+1
    cart_products = serpy.MethodField(required=False)  # N+1 !!!
    cart_services = serpy.MethodField(required=False)  # N+1 !!!

    def get_cart_products(self, obj: Order):
        # N+1 detected here.
        return self.SimpleOrderComponentSerializer(obj.cart.filter(listing__product__isnull=False), many=True).data

    def get_cart_services(self, obj: Order):
        # N+1 detected here. Curiously, the number of N+1 queries detected differs between the two.
        return self.SimpleOrderComponentSerializer(obj.cart.filter(listing__service__isnull=False), many=True).data
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my prefetch does not work here. Django Debug Toolbar confirms that it is not a false positive:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "shop_ordercomponent" INNER JOIN "shop_listing" ON ("shop_ordercomponent"."listing_id" = "shop_listing"."id") INNER JOIN "shop_product" ON ("shop_listing"."product_id" = "shop_product"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "shop_service" ON ("shop_listing"."service_id" = "shop_service"."id") WHERE ("shop_ordercomponent"."order_id" = 2 AND "shop_listing"."product_id" IS NOT NULL)
  25 similar queries.
```

If I inspect `obj` in `get_cart_services` or `get_cart_products`, I see that `obj._prefetched_objects_cache["cart"]` is a `QuerySet` of `OrderComponent`. If I inspect `obj` in `SimpleOrderComponentSerializer.get_product_name`, for example, I see nothing in `obj._prefetched_objects_cache["cart"]`, which I don't expect, since `listing.product` and `listing.service` are `select_related`-ed, not `prefetch_related`-ed.

I admit I don't fully understand how this works, but I assume `select_related` populates one-to-one relationships greedily in one query rather than lazily waiting for the related object to be requested.

My initial `prefetch_related` does not "carry over" into the inner serializer's `MethodField` handler by the looks of it. `nplusone` logs:

```
Potential n+1 query detected on `Order.cart`
Potential n+1 query detected on `Order.cart`
Potential n+1 query detected on `Order.cart`
...  # Repeated many times. Multiple warnings printed for each object.
```

Is it because `cart` is a "reverse" relationship? Any help understanding why this isn't working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by annotating the required information in `get_queryset` and getting that instead. That way, the prefetched information will be stored in each instance.